# In Python, Pandas. How to subset dataframe by WOM - 'Week of the Month'?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I want to be able to subset a df by week of the month, similar to what you can do with day of the week or month.

```
sample = df[df.index.month == 12]
```

So is there any way to do this??

```
sample = df[df.index.WOM == 1]
```

I know that if I type the line above you get AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'WOM', is just for reference to understand what I want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the value of [`.weekofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekofyear.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekofyear) and the same value at the beginning of month and the difference of these two should give the week of month; for example:

```
>>> days = ['2014-02-01', '2014-06-10', '2014-08-30', '2014-11-22']
>>> idx = pd.to_datetime(days)
>>> idx.weekofyear
array([ 5, 24, 35, 47], dtype=int32)
```

for the beginning of month you can subtract the `.day` from index itself:

```
>>> mon = idx - pd.to_timedelta(idx.day - 1, unit='D')
>>> mon.weekofyear
array([ 5, 22, 31, 44], dtype=int32)
```

and week of month would be:

```
>>> 1 + idx.weekofyear - mon.weekofyear
array([1, 3, 5, 4], dtype=int32)
```